# Create file using path from lineEdit from another class

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, signals-slots, qlineedit

In my project I have a `MainWindow.cpp` file which contains "New Txt File" button. The button opens the `NewTxtFileName` dialog in which I can create a new text.txt file by pressing the "Create" button.

Then a Save Dialog opens and I can choose the directory and the name of the new file. When done, the full path of the file is printed inside the "Path" lineEdit which can be used to open a second dialog. The second Dialog is `WriteFileDialog` where I can add the name of the author and by clicking "Ok", the file is written.

[image]

It seems though that the path of the file in the lineEdit is not used by the `MainWindow` class in order to call the `WriteFileDialog`.

If I replace the `TxtFile` variable in the `NewTxtFileName::getpath()` class with `QString TxtFile= QDir::homePath+QDir::separator()+"untitled.txt"` then the second dilog opens, writting the file and the contents in the new location.

It is important that the file path to pe printed in "Path" lineEdit. How can I properly use the desired file location and name to open the `WriteFileDialog` and save it?

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::createTxtFileName()
{
    newtxtfilename = new NewTxtFileName(this);
    connect(newtxtfilename,SIGNAL(ready()),this,SLOT(writefile()));
    newtxtfilename->show();
    newtxtfilename->activateWindow();
}


void MainWindow::writefile()
{
    newfilename = new NewTxtFileName(this);
    QString fileName = newfilename->getpath();

    if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;

    newwritedialog = new WriteFileDialog(this,fileName);
    connect(newwritedialog,SIGNAL(opensignal()),this,SLOT(openfile()));
    newwritedialog->show();
    newwritedialog->activateWindow();

}
```

**NewTxtFileName.cpp**

```
void NewTxtFileName::on_CreateFileButton_clicked()
{
    QString filePathName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("File Name"),
            QDir::homePath()+QDir::separator()+"untitled.txt","txt Files (*.txt)");

    ui->Path->setText(filePathName);
    if (filePathName.isEmpty()) return;
}

QString NewTxtFileName::getpath()
{
    QString TxtFile= ui->Path->text();
    //QString TxtFile= QDir::homePath+QDir::separator()+"untitled.txt"
    QString path = TxtFile;
    return path;
}

void NewTxtFileName::on_OkButton_accepted() //15/5
{
    ready();
    close();
}
```

**WriteFileDialog.cpp**

```
WriteFileDialog::WriteFileDialog(QWidget *parent,QString fileName) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::WriteFileDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->buttonBox,SIGNAL(accepted()),this,SLOT(create()));

    txtfileName = fileName;
    setWindowTitle(QFileInfo(fileName).fileName());

}

void WriteFileDialog::create() {

    QString fileText = "Author Name : ";
    QString fileText += ui->AuthorlineEdit->text();

    QFile file(txtfileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;
    QTextStream textStream(&file);
    textStream.flush();
    textStream << fileText;
    file.close();

    emit opensignal(txtfileName);

}

WriteFileDialog::~WriteFileDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are creating a new instance of **NewTxtFileName** where you don't set the path.

I have to say that your code is a little messy, I think you should rewrite the signal and slot workflow, anyway just commenting this line should work if **writefile** is always called after **createTxtFileName**:

```
void MainWindow::writefile()
{
    //You are creating a new instance of the NewTxtFileName window where you never set the path
    //newfilename = new NewTxtFileName(this);
    QString fileName = newfilename->getpath();

    //also try using QDebug so that you know what fileName contains
    qDebug() << fileName;
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;

    newwritedialog = new WriteFileDialog(this,fileName);
    connect(newwritedialog,SIGNAL(opensignal()),this,SLOT(openfile()));
    newwritedialog->show();
    newwritedialog->activateWindow();

}
```

Comment: Thats right. The Path line was empty in the new "NewTxtFileName" window, so no file was created. Didn't see that thanks.